# How to connect "user" table to "tasks" table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a database called "to_do_list". I want users to be able to log in and create tasks. I have two tables in "to_do_list":

```
tasks:
task_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
task VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
importance VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
due_date DATE NOT NULL

user:
user_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
password VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
```

How do I connect these two tables so a user can sign in and create tasks? I know I have to create a foreign key, but every time I do so, I can neither log in or create tasks. Once I remove the foreign key, everything works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is a task related to a user? Does a user have tasks? Can a task belong to one user at a time?

I asssume both answers are Yes.

If so, then you will need to add a user_id column to your tasks table, and mark it as the foreign key. This is used to capture which user your task is related to.

You can do this by adding this line to your CREATE TABLE statement for tasks (or ALTER TABLE):

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
```

If you're having login issues, then this would be another issue. Perhaps your login logic is from an incorrect SQL query or some other programming logic.

Comment: I added a user_id row to the tasks table and tried to mark it as the foreign key but I'm getting this error: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row.

Comment: I see. I think it's happening because there are task records which have no user ID. So, I think you'll need to add the user_id field (which you've done), then update the task records to set a user_id value, then add the foreign key. Alternatively, you can delete all of your records in the task table - not sure if that will be a good idea for you though.